# FineUploader start with delete template

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I'm using FineUploader, but i have one problem. The user can upload a image, but an image might be there already (previous uploaded). When there is already an image (previous uploaded), i want to show the delete link, when there's no image.. i what to show the upload link.

How can i toggle between these two states? Specially on the page loads.. and there is already an image there.

Right know im just removing and adding the links manually.

```
$('.fine-uploader0 .qq-upload-list').append('Remove');
```

Can i have a template for each one of those? and switch between them?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite clear on your requirements here.  Also, it's not clear how you are making the determination regarding if an image has already been uploaded.  Please edit your answer to show all of your client-side code.  Also, please provide a description of you application.  Again, it's a bit hard to determine exactly what you are trying to do here or what specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @RayNicholus: In your stackoverflow profile.. there is already one photo of you. So you already have one photo in the "plugin". Not complicated. If that plugin was FineUploader... how do you tell the plugin that there is already one picture?

Answer (score 0):

There is no good cross-browser way to determine if a file has already been submitted.  Some might say that comparing file names is acceptable, but it's not.  That will fail in many situations and is not a reasonable choice.  Even if there was a reasonable way to make this determination client-side (cross-browser), there is no way to tell Fine Uploader that a duplicate file exists.

If you want to prevent a file from being submitted, you can do so by either returning false outright from a ["validate"](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#validate) event handler, or you can return a [`qq.Promise`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/async-tasks-and-promises.html) that you later call `failure` on after you have asynchronously determined that the file should be rejected.  The asynchronous part comes in when you use FileReader to calculate an MD5 hash for the file client-side, and then either make an ajax call to your server to determine if another file with a matching hash exists, or compare it with other hashes you have stored client-side for files submitted during the current session.  Computing this hash may be quite expensive though.

Answer (score 0):

You want to display a previously uploaded item. There is no shortcut to this but it is easy, from the onComplete of FineUploader, here is some code for how I display photos, you could use this to display the previous photo.

```
   onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                    if (responseJSON.success) {
                        $('#file-' + id).removeClass('alert-info')
                                        .addClass('alert-success')
                                        .html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> ' +
                                              'Successfully saved ' +
                                              '“' + fileName + '”' +
                                              '<br><img src="/images/message_ok.png" alt="' + fileName + '">');
                        $.when(loadThumbs()).done(function () {
                            $(".qq-upload-list > .alert-success").remove();
                        });
                        myprettyprompt.success("Success!");

   function loadThumbs() {

        var PhotoRequest = {
            propertyId: <%=PropertyId %>
            }
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var n = currentTime.getTime();
        postUrl = "myurl?nocache="+n; //use nocache, mobile safari IOS6 caches ajax urls!

        $.ajax(
        {
            url: postUrl,
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(PhotoRequest),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                loadThumbsCallBack(data.d);
            }
        });

    }

    function loadThumbsCallBack(data) {
        var items = [];
        var photoTypeSelectList = 
            '<select class="form-control" data-id="{id}">' +   
            '<option value="Misc">Misc</option>' +    
            '</select>'
        var defaultCheckBox = '<label><small>First Photo (Default)</small></label><input type="checkbox" class="default-photo-cbx" data-id="{id}" {checked} />';
        var itemTemplate = '<li><img data-photo-type="{photo_type}" data-id="{id}" src="{url}" /><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" href="#"></a><div>' + photoTypeSelectList + defaultCheckBox + '</div></li>';

        //clear current image thumbs
        $('#imageThumbs').empty();

        $.each(data, function (index, element) {
            var item;
            var checked = '';

            if(element.DefaultPhoto){
                checked = 'checked="checked"';
            }
            item = itemTemplate.replace(/{id}/g, element.Id).replace('{url}', element.Url).replace(/{photo_type}/g, element.PhotoType).replace('{checked}',checked);

            //mark photo type selected if photo type exists
            if (element.PhotoType !== null) {
                item = item.replace('value="' + element.PhotoType + '"', 'value="' + element.PhotoType + '" selected="selected"');
            }

            items.push(item);
        });


        $('#imageThumbs').append(items.join(''));


        $("#imageThumbs > li > a").click(function () {
            deleteThumb($(this).prev().attr('data-id'));
        });

        $("#imageThumbs > li > div >select").change(function () {
            updatePhotoType($(this).attr('data-id'), $(this).find('option:selected').text());
        });

        $("#imageThumbs > li > div > .default-photo-cbx").change(function () {
            var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

            //ignore if unchecking
            if(isChecked){
                UpdateDefaultPhoto($(this).attr('data-id'), $(this).is(':checked'));
            }
        });
    }

 <div id="bootstrapped-fine-uploader">
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul id="imageThumbs">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
```